# How to set a destination for shutil.copyfileobj?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py, uuid, shutil

This code saves a discord image to the folder which it is in. I tried to set a destination for the save file, but I haven't found anything on the shutil website which sets the destination. I tried to put a destination in the shutil.copyfileobj brackets, but that didn't work. Also I an relatively new to coding.

This is the code:

```
import uuid
import requests
import shutil
from discord.ext import commands

class filesaver:

    @bot.command()
    async def save(ctx):
        try:
            url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
        except IndexError:
            print("Error: No Attachments")
            await ctx.send("No Attachments detected!")
        
        else:
            if url[0:26] == "https://cdn.discordapp.com":
                r= requests.get(url, stream=True)
                imageName = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
                with open(imageName, 'wb') as out_file:
                    print('saving image: ' + imageName)
                    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)

        await ctx.send(f"text")
```

Comment: You need to make `imageName` contain the complete path with the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `imageName` doesn't contain a path, so it opens in whatever is your current working directory.  That's a bit unpredictable.  It's also easy to fix.

```
from pathlib import Path
imageName = str(Path.home() / Path(str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'))
```

You can of course replace `Path.home()` with any destination path you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used this instead, and worked:

```py
res = requests.get(imageLink, stream=True)
with open("directory/myImage.png", "wb") as img:
    shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, img)
```

Hope this helps...